# How to access and replace text in certain paragraphs using OPENXML powertools case by case

Tags: c#, openxml, power-tools-for-xml

I am trying to redact some word files using c# and openxml. I need to do controlled replace of the numbers with certain phrase. Each word file contains different amount of info. I want to use OPENXML powertools for this purspose.

I used normal openxml method to replace but it very unreliable and gets random errors such as zero length error.I used regex replace and that seems to work but it replaces it through out the document which is highly undesirable.

Here is some snippet of the code :

```
private void redact_Replaceall(string wfile)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wfile, true))
                {
                    var ydoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
                    IEnumerable<XElement> content = ydoc.Descendants(W.body);



                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d{2,3}");
                    int count1 = OpenXmlPowerTools.OpenXmlRegex.Match(content, regex);


                    int count2 = OpenXmlPowerTools.OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, regex, replace_text, null);

                    statusBar1.Text = "Try 1: Found: " + count1 + ", Replaced: " + count2;


                    doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Replace all exprienced error: " + e.Message);
            }

        }
```

Basically, I want to do this redaction based on content of paragraph. I am able to get the paragraphs using but not the id's

```
IEnumerable<XElement> content = ydoc.Descendants(W.p);
```

Here is my approach using the normal openxml method but I get alot of errors depending on the file.

```
  foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph para in bod.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>())
                                    {

                                        foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                                        {
                                            foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                                            {
                                                string temp = text.Text;
                                                int firstlength = first.Length + 1;
                                                int secondlength = second.Length + 1;
                                                if (text.Text.Contains(first) && !(temp.Length > firstlength))
                                                {
                                                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace(first, "DELETED");

                                                }

                                                if (text.Text.Contains(second) && !(temp.Length > secondlength))
                                                {
                                                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace(second, "DELETED");

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
```

Here is the last new approach but I am stuck on it

```
   private void redact_Replacebadones(string wfile)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wfile, true))
                {
                    var ydoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
                  /*  from XElement xele in ydoc.Root.Elements();
                    List<string> lhsElements = xele.Elements("lhs")
                               .Select(el => el.Attribute("id").Value)
                               .ToList();
                               */
                    /// XElement
                    IEnumerable<XElement> content = ydoc.Descendants(W.p);

                   foreach (var p in content )

                    {
                        if (p.Value.Contains("each") && !p.Value.Contains("DELETED"))
                        {

                            string to_overwrite = p.Value;
                            Regex regexop = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d{2,3}");

                            regexop.Replace(to_overwrite, "Deleted");

                            p.SetValue(to_overwrite);

                            MessageBox.Show("NAME :" + p.GetParagraphInfo() +" VValue:"+to_overwrite);
                        }

                    }


                    doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Replace each exprienced error: " + e.Message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late. OpenXML Power tools by Eric white has a Function SearchAndReplace where you can replace Text content, so you don't have to handle it with RegEx.
This function handles also text which is splitted into runs. (If you edit a word, a word can be splittet in runs, so you dint find the search phrase directly.)
May be this helps somebody.