# How to update an WmlDocument from OpenXMLRegex

Tags: c#, openxml, power-tools-for-xml

I'm trying to process several word docs by

1. merging them and them with `OpenXMLPowerTools.DocumentBuilder` (which requires and outputs WmlDocuments)
2. Remove all comments via `OpenXMLRegex.Replace`

Each of these steps works fine independently. However, `OpenXMLRegex` requires and modifies an `IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>`. The problem comes when mapping this enumerable back to the `WmlDocument`.

You cannot set the `WmlDocument` elements or `MainDocumentPart`.
There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036159/how-to-access-and-replace-text-in-certain-paragraphs-using-openxml-powertools-ca), of modifying a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordProcessingDocument`. However, I can't find a way to map that back to a `WmlDocument` either.

```
WmlDocument RemoveComments(WmlDocument doc)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"/\*([^/\*])*\*/");
    string commentArtifact = "";

    List<XElement> matches = new List<XElement>();
    var docElements = doc.MainDocumentPart.Elements();
    OpenXmlRegex.Replace(docElements, regex, commentArtifact, null);

    //TODO: How to map back to WmlDocument
    return doc;
}
```

I'd strongly prefer to output a modified WmlDocument for consistent further processing.

I'm using OpenXmlPowerTools version 4.5.3.2